# Vuforia - Getting Started in Android

Tags: android, vuforia

Android 2.3.3

I am new to Vuforia and Augmented Reality in particular. So, please excuse me if this is very basic question.

I was able to download and run the sample application from Vuforia on Text Recognition and Image Recognition. Now I set out to create a sample application(Image Targeting) of my own.

Here is what I did ::: Following the steps given in Vuforia

1. Downloaded the SDK from Vuforia.
2. Created a Database using Target Manager in the developer console of Vuforia.
3. Adding a Target - I uploaded an image into the database that i just created. It's an image of letter A.
4. Updating Targets - skipped this step
5. Downloading Targets - Selected the image and clicked "Download selected targets" and got a zip file in my system. I extracted it and now i see two files, one is a .dat and another is a .xml file.

Now I have no clue of what to do, from here...

Here is what I wanted to do.. When I scan the Image A with my application, it should show, you have scanned A. That's it - As simple as that.

Can someone tell me what I need to do from here..

I tried searching for tutorials on Android part of vuforia, but I really didn't get any help from web. Please guide me incase you have some links with you.

Thanks in advance!!

---

Thanks for your quick response Sushil

Edit 1 ::: Okie, I see them in the Assets folder. I will add them in the Assets folder too. Now, can I change the files in the sample application, with my files(that I downloaded) and change the references, to make the sample application work for my files? Is it that simple?

Comment: it is more simple that :). Once you get a grip AR will turn out to be very simple :). Please do accept the answer once it works for u :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep those two target image files (.dat and .xml in the assets folder) and then use them in the code.

Check the sample application. You will see .xml and .dat files inside the `assets` folder

Comment: and what about the code to use the image recognition? is there any docs provided from vuforia?